# How to make import schema of projection tab in Azure Data Factory work?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using Data Flow in Azure Data Factory. I have source linked with database. I want to import the schema. but its coming blank.

[image]

however, when I click Data preview then I do see the data with all columns. Then why it says "No columns exists in the schema"?

Comment: Try to refresh the browser or change the browser, still reporting this error?

Comment: @Joseph Xu 
Yes it is actually. I tried refreshing it but no luck

Comment: @DineshMadhup Please go to the source dataset and import the schema again.

Comment: @LeonYue No matter how many times I try its same. I doubt there is something going on with data connection

Comment: @DineshMadhup refresh the connection, and change to another source file to check if it happen again. Maybe it's just a bug.

Comment: @DineshMadhup is it solved now? did you set allow schema drift or validate schema?

Comment: what do you see when you click Data Preview?

Comment: @Leon Yue YES Schema drift box is checked.

Comment: @DineshMadhup that's so strange. Can you see the data preview like Mark said?

Comment: @LeonYue 
@ Mark Kromer
After I refresh the connection, nothing after data refresh. However, when I create new data flow it works but the data flow I created day before has still connection issue. It looks weird.

Comment: @Leon Yue I do see this error when I test connection on debug mode: DF-FLO-001 - Input transformation 'Cp' not found - [677],EXE-0001,Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph

Comment: @DineshMadhup it's very hard to find the root cause of the error. We also can not repeat it. I'm glad that the solution is create a new data flow and every thing works ok. May I post is as answer?

Comment: Hi @DineshMadhup, have a good day!  Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to find the root cause of the error. It may be a bug or something else. We also can not repeat it.

I'm glad that create a new data flow and every thing works ok.

That is the solution and this This can be beneficial to other community members.

If anyone have the same experience, any suggestions will be appreciated.